# golang initilize inner struct object in nested structs

Tags: go

I have a nested struct

```
type Posts struct {
    Id        int
    CreatedAt time.Time
    Data      struct {
        Title    string
        UserName string
    }
}
```

I want to create a Data object but `var innerData Posts.Data` doesn't seem to work. I don't want to create separate `Data struct` because I'm planning to avoid name collusions by having multiple structs which will have different inner structs named Data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `Posts.Data` isn't the name of a type. The only thing you could do is `var innerData struct{ ... }`, which I'm sure you don't want to because then you would have repetition and need to make changes in two places. Otherwise, you have to give it a name. That name doesn't have to be `Data`, it can be `PostData` or something to make it unique.